# Why apt-get update works but upgrade gives 403 Forbidden?

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

I have a working Ubuntu 12.04 environment behind a proxy with all settings correct but `sudo apt-get upgrade` fails to work with error `403  Forbidden` for every server. However, `sudo apt-get update` works fine as the list is updated and I get a Hit for every server. Furthermore, all other system internet accesses work with the configured proxy server e.g.

```
azg@hercules:~$ wget --spider http://www.google.co.in/
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2014-08-01 10:21:27--  http://www.google.co.in/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
```

I also have about five other exact same Ubuntu boxes and they all update/upgrade no problems. In fact, this machine with the issue is a clone of one of those working ones.

How can I troubleshoot this? would it be a missing configuration or rule in the Proxy Server?

UPDATE: here is the output of running `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal
  linux-image-generic-lts-quantal
The following packages will be upgraded:
  acpi-support compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default cups
  cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-ppdc dbus dbus-x11 file firefox
  firefox-globalmenu firefox-locale-en google-chrome-stable kdelibs-bin
  kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools libcups2 libcups2:i386 libcupscgi1
  libcupsdriver1 libcupsimage2 libcupsimage2:i386 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1
  libdbus-1-3 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdecoration0 libjpeg-turbo8
  libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg-turbo8-dev libkcmutils4 libkde3support4
  libkdeclarative5 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4
  libkemoticons4 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkio5 libkjsapi4
  libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4
  libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4
  libktexteditor4 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libmagic1 libminiupnpc8
  libmysqlclient18:i386 libnepomuk4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4
  libplasma3 libsolid4 libtasn1-3 libtasn1-3:i386 libtasn1-3-dev
  libthreadweaver4 lightdm linux-generic-lts-quantal linux-libc-dev
  mysql-common r-base-core r-base-dev r-cran-class r-cran-mgcv r-doc-html
  r-recommended thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu thunderbird-gnome-support
  thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb thunderbird-locale-en-us
  transmission-common transmission-gtk update-manager update-manager-core
  update-notifier update-notifier-common wget
95 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 171 MB of archives.
After this operation, 18.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  r-base-core r-base-dev r-cran-class r-cran-mgcv r-doc-html r-recommended
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? Err http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main google-chrome-stable amd64 36.0.1985.125-1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ r-base-core 3.1.1-1precise0
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libdbus-1-3 i386 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.5
  403  Forbidden
Err http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ r-base-dev 3.1.1-1precise0
  403  Forbidden
Err http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ r-cran-class 7.3-11-1precise0
  403  Forbidden
Err http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ r-cran-mgcv 1.8-2-1precise0
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main wget amd64 1.13.4-2ubuntu1.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libjpeg-turbo8-dev amd64 1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libjpeg-turbo8 i386 1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libjpeg-turbo8 amd64 1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ r-doc-html 3.1.1-1precise0
  403  Forbidden
Err http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ r-recommended 3.1.1-1precise0
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libdbus-1-3 i386 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.5
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main lightdm amd64 1.2.3-0ubuntu2.5
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main update-manager all 1:0.156.14.17
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main update-manager-core amd64 1:0.156.14.17
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main update-notifier amd64 0.119ubuntu8.7
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main update-notifier-common all 0.119ubuntu8.7
  503  Service Unavailable
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libdbus-1-3 amd64 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.5
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libtasn1-3-dev amd64 2.10-1ubuntu1.2
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main compiz-gnome amd64 1:0.9.7.12-0ubuntu4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main compiz-plugins-default amd64 1:0.9.7.12-0ubuntu4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libdecoration0 amd64 1:0.9.7.12-0ubuntu4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main compiz-core amd64 1:0.9.7.12-0ubuntu4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libtasn1-3 i386 2.10-1ubuntu1.2
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libtasn1-3 amd64 2.10-1ubuntu1.2
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libcups2 amd64 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libcups2 i386 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main compiz all 1:0.9.7.12-0ubuntu4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libcupsmime1 amd64 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libcupscgi1 amd64 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libcupsimage2 i386 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libcupsimage2 amd64 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libcupsppdc1 amd64 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main cups-common all 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main cups-bsd amd64 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main cups-client amd64 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main cups-ppdc amd64 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main cups amd64 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libcupsdriver1 amd64 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main mysql-common all 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libmysqlclient18 i386 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main dbus amd64 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.5
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main file amd64 5.09-2ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libmagic1 amd64 5.09-2ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main acpi-support amd64 0.140.2
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main dbus-x11 amd64 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.5
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main firefox amd64 31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main firefox-globalmenu amd64 31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main firefox-locale-en amd64 31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main liblightdm-gobject-1-0 amd64 1.2.3-0ubuntu2.5
  503  Service Unavailable
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkdeclarative5 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main kdoctools amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main kdelibs-bin amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkjsembed4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkdesu5 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkhtml5 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libktexteditor4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libplasma3 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkrosscore4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkcmutils4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkde3support4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkmediaplayer4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkdewebkit5 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkparts4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libknewstuff3-4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libknotifyconfig4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libnepomukutils4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libnepomukquery4a amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkpty4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libknewstuff2-4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkfile4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkio5 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libnepomuk4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkntlm4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkjsapi4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkdnssd4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkidletime4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkdeui5 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkdecore5 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main kdelibs5-data all 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main kdelibs5-plugins amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libkemoticons4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libsolid4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libthreadweaver4 amd64 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libminiupnpc8 amd64 1.6-3ubuntu1.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main linux-generic-lts-quantal amd64 3.5.0.54.59
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.2.0-67.101
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main thunderbird-locale-en amd64 1:31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main thunderbird amd64 1:31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main thunderbird-gnome-support amd64 1:31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main thunderbird-globalmenu amd64 1:31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main thunderbird-locale-en-gb all 1:31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main thunderbird-locale-en-us all 1:31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main transmission-common all 2.51-0ubuntu1.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main transmission-gtk amd64 2.51-0ubuntu1.4
  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-3_1.4.18-1ubuntu1.5_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-3_1.4.18-1ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtasn1-3/libtasn1-3-dev_2.10-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtasn1-3/libtasn1-3_2.10-1ubuntu1.2_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtasn1-3/libtasn1-3_2.10-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcups2_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcups2_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcupsmime1_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcupscgi1_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcupsimage2_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcupsimage2_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcupsppdc1_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/cups-common_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/cups-bsd_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/cups-client_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/cups-ppdc_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/cups_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wget/wget_1.13.4-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_36.0.1985.125-1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcupsdriver1_1.5.3-0ubuntu8.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8-dev_1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8_1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.4_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8_1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-common_5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/libmysqlclient18_5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dbus/dbus_1.4.18-1ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lightdm/lightdm_1.2.3-0ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager_0.156.14.17_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager-core_0.156.14.17_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-notifier/update-notifier_0.119ubuntu8.7_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-notifier/update-notifier-common_0.119ubuntu8.7_all.deb  503  Service Unavailable
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/file/file_5.09-2ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/file/libmagic1_5.09-2ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/acpi-support/acpi-support_0.140.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-gnome_0.9.7.12-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-plugins-default_0.9.7.12-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/libdecoration0_0.9.7.12-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-core_0.9.7.12-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz_0.9.7.12-0ubuntu4_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dbus/dbus-x11_1.4.18-1ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-globalmenu_31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-en_31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkdeclarative5_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/kdoctools_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/kdelibs-bin_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkjsembed4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkdesu5_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkhtml5_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libktexteditor4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libplasma3_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkrosscore4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkcmutils4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkde3support4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkmediaplayer4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkdewebkit5_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkparts4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libknewstuff3-4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libknotifyconfig4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libnepomukutils4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libnepomukquery4a_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkpty4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libknewstuff2-4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkfile4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkio5_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libnepomuk4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkntlm4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkjsapi4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkdnssd4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkidletime4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkdeui5_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkdecore5_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/kdelibs5-data_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/kdelibs5-plugins_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libkemoticons4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libsolid4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kde4libs/libthreadweaver4_4.8.5-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lightdm/liblightdm-gobject-1-0_1.2.3-0ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb  503  Service Unavailable
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/miniupnpc/libminiupnpc8_1.6-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-lts-quantal/linux-generic-lts-quantal_3.5.0.54.59_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.2.0-67.101_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/precise/r-base-core_3.1.1-1precise0_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/precise/r-base-dev_3.1.1-1precise0_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/precise/r-cran-class_7.3-11-1precise0_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/precise/r-cran-mgcv_1.8-2-1precise0_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/precise/r-doc-html_3.1.1-1precise0_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/precise/r-recommended_3.1.1-1precise0_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-locale-en_31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird_31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-gnome-support_31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-globalmenu_31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-locale-en-gb_31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-locale-en-us_31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/transmission/transmission-common_2.51-0ubuntu1.4_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/transmission/transmission-gtk_2.51-0ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: A log for sample run of apt-get upgrade would help.

Comment: How do you get the log? simply the generated stdout?

Comment: Have you installed apache? And yes, just the stdout.